# Install Microsoft Word on Mac OS Mojave

Tags: macos, mac, catalina, mojave, ms-office

App Store is not letting me download the previous version. The current version is for Mac OS Catalina and above. I had it running last year but deleted the app.

Does any one know how to install Microsoft Word on Mac OS Mojave?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Microsoft maintains a comprehensive history of older versions of software that may boggle your mind in its scope.

- https://macadmins.software

You can see they’ve hi-lighted minimum system versions and there is a cut off as Mojave has fallen off the “current release train”.

You’ll want Word downloaded from the 10/12/21   16.54.0 21101001 line of office releases if you can’t download it as a previous purchase from the Mac App Store. Below are the full suite installs and word update direct downloads from Microsoft.

- https://officecdnmac.microsoft.com/pr/C1297A47-86C4-4C1F-97FA-950631F94777/MacAutoupdate/Microsoft_Office_16.54.21101001_Installer.pkg
- https://officecdnmac.microsoft.com/pr/C1297A47-86C4-4C1F-97FA-950631F94777/MacAutoupdate/Microsoft_Word_16.54.21101001_Updater.pkg

Comment: Very good answer, in case no one else says so! :)

Comment: Credit here goes the the Mac team at Microsoft for listening to people supporting their product - the engineers, managers and document team there are amazing. I just knew where to look.

Comment: Very useful! A doubt - If we download the *suite installer*, do we also have to download the Word update, Excel update etc.? Are the "updates" security / feature updates or stand-alone installed for Word, Excel etc.?

Comment: I’m not sure I understand it can answer in comments. Would you let me know if you ask a follow on question with some details on what  specific packages or update you’re considering?

Answer (score 8):

On your Mac, go to

```
App Store -> View my account.
```

App store will show all your purchased apps. Click on cloud to download Microsoft Word. It shows a prompt like:

[image]

Click on the Download button.